# Rails : belongs_to and has_many using non-standard ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got two models, Item and Product as follows:

```
irb(main):007:0> Item
=> Item(id: integer, identification_number: string, production_date: date, 
        created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, going_in: boolean)
irb(main):008:0> Product
=> Product(id: integer, sku: string, barcode_identification: string, 
           created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Think of this as an item is of a particular product.

I've managed to refer all the items of a particular product (Product.find(1).items) via

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :foreign_key => "identification_number", 
                   :primary_key => "barcode_identification"
end
```

but I can't seem to refer the Product of a particular item.
This is what I've got now:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :identification_number
  belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => "barcode_identification"
end
```

And as far as my understanding re: databases are concerned, that should work. Except that it doesn't. Maybe I'm missing out on something here? I'm fairly new to rails (around a month or less.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Does it have to be a `belongs_to`?  Since you're specifying both primary and foreign key, why not

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :foreign_key => "identification_number", 
                   :primary_key => "barcode_identification"
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :product, :foreign_key => "barcode_identification", 
                    :primary_key => "identification_number"
end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why has_one works and belongs_to doesn't for this scenario? I would expect belongs_to to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Interesting. Worked for me. Thanks. Still wondering why belongs_to doesn't work

Comment: @RonyVarghese `belongs_to` should work in Item if you specify the foreign & primary keys correctly: 
`  belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => "identification_number",  :primary_key => "barcode_identification"` (note that the keys are the same as in the `has_many`!)

Check out the docs for these two methods to see the subtle distinctions:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one and http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

Answer (score 1):

You must have a foreign key in your items table.
I'm assuming barcode_identification_id is a column (foreign key) in items table.
If you have some other column then just replace it with that.

Try like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :barcode_identification
  has_many :items, :foreign_key => "barcode_identification_id"
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :identification_number
  belongs_to :product
end
```